# HtmlAgilityPack (C#) can't read past hidden text

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

using the following url:

[link to search results page](http://www.voachinese.com/search/search2.aspx#all%7C%E5%8A%A0%E5%B7%9E%E6%97%B1%E8%B1%A1%E4%B8%8D%E5%87%8F%20%E5%BC%80%E6%BA%90%E8%8A%82%E6%B5%81%E5%A3%B0%E5%A3%B0%E6%80%A5%7C0%7Callzones%7Cmin%7Cnow%7Cbanner)

I am trying to first scrape the text from the a tag from this html that can be seen from the source code when viewed with Firebug:

```html
<div id="search-results" class="search_results">
  <div class="searchResultItem">
    <div class="searchResultImage photo">
      <h3 class="black">
        <a class="linkmed " href="/content/1/2484243.html">加州旱象不减 开源节流声声急</a>
      </h3>
      <p class="resultPubDate">15.10.2014 06:08 </p>
      <p class="resultText">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="more-results">
```

But what I get back when I scrape the page is:

```html
<div class="search_results" id="search-results"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$cpAB$cp1$hidSearchType" id="hidSearchType">      
</div> 
<p class="more-results">
```

Is there anyway to view the source the way Firebug does?

Comment: Are the results ajax loaded? It appears the DOM is changing after the page has loaded..

Answer (score 0):

How are you scraping the page? Use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and check the request and the response for dynamic pages like these ones. The reason why Firebug sees more is because all of the dynamic elements have loaded already when you are viewing it in your browser, when in fact your scraping method is only one piece of the puzzle (the initial HTML).

Hint: For this search page, you will see that the request for the results data is actually a) a separate GET request with b) a long query string and c) a cookie on the header, which returns a JSON object containing the data. This is why the link you posted just gives me "undefined," because it does not contain the search data.

Comment: here is the link: http://www.voachinese.com/search/search2.aspx#all|%E5%8A%A0%E5%B7%9E%E6%97%B1%E8%B1%A1%E4%B8%8D%E5%87%8F%20%E5%BC%80%E6%BA%90%E8%8A%82%E6%B5%81%E5%A3%B0%E5%A3%B0%E6%80%A5%7C0|allzones|min|now|banner

Comment: It's the same. Why don't you: Use another browser or delete your history/cache/cookies and then access the same link yourself so you know what we're seeing? In any case, why don't you try my advice? :)